# Can I use a middleware to limit the post per kind of user in mongo db and express js? Is there any other best way?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, payment

My app have a subscription system with a different type of user according of how much they pay, every kind of user have a limit of posts monthly according to their plan, What is the best way to implement this in a mern stack?

Answer (score 0):

you can have several approaches to that.
Or checking each time someone submits a "post" to your product how much he has and if can he send the request with a middleware.

Or having the data of the current "balance/used time" in a token for example and each time he wants to do this post again to check in the token if he already passed his limit(so you don't need to fetch the data from the DB).

And then of course at the end create a new token with the updated information.